# Is There a Deadline for Forming Political Parties before a US Presidential Election?

Tags: criminal-law, constitutional-law, politics

Can I legally, with respect to the FEC, form a political party such as Kanye's "Birthday Party" just before a national election as he has?  This article suggests not:

"... you can only register a political party at certain times of the year. For instance, you may not be able to register a new political party shortly before an election."

https://www.unstrippedvoice.com/4286-you-can-create-a-new-political-party-heres-how-to-do-it/

The FEC website does not state a specific deadline:

https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/registering-political-party/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form a political party any time you want and never tell the FEC. This is in part because under the law creating the FEC, "political party" has a [specialized meaning](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/30101#16):

> The term “political party” means an association, committee, or
> organization which nominates a candidate for election to any Federal
> office whose name appears on the election ballot as the candidate of
> such association, committee, or organization.

Given that, the [authorized (campaign) committee](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/30101#6) has to file a statement of organization within 10 days of designation under [section 30102(e)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/30102#e_1), and that has to be done within 15 days of the candidate becoming a candidate. The relevant regulations ([11 CFR Part 102](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d1d591c8f672fc3aab343ad502201b78&mc=true&node=pt11.1.102&rgn=div5)) do not suggest that there is any restriction on when this can be done.

The only thing that I can suggest is that they were thinking of state-level restrictions on getting your name on the ballot.